# Enderton's Elements of Set Theory Scott's Trick Exercise (page 207 problem 31)

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

> **31.** Define kard $A$ to be the collection of all sets $B$ such that (i) $A$ is equinumerous to $B$, and (ii) nothing of rank less than rank $B$ is equinumerous to $B$.
>
> (a) Show that kard $A$ is a set.
>   (b) Show that kard $A$ is nonempty.
>   (c) Show that for any sets $A$ and $B$,
>
> $$\text{kard }A=\text{kard }B\quad\text{iff}\quad A\approx B$$

I understand the exercise by rewriting it into the following Theorem (which I believe is essentially what's being asked to prove ignoring (c) which should be proved as a corollary)

> **Theorem** (Scott's Trick) For each set $A$, there exists a unique collection $\mathcal{C}$ of sets whose elements are exactly those elements $B$ such that $B\sim A$ and for each set $C$, if $\mathrm{rank}(C)<\mathrm{rank}(B)$, then $C\nsim B$.

My instincts tell me we should start with the ordinal $\mathrm{rank}(A)$, and find the least ordinal $\alpha$ less than or equal such that $V_\alpha$ has the property for $\mathcal{C}$. Is this right? All this does is prove (a), but how does one show (b) and (c)?

Any insight or rigorous solution is much appreciated!

---

The definition of $\mathrm{rank}(A)$ is the least ordinal $\beta
$ such that $A\subseteq V_\beta$ where $V_\beta$ is the $\beta$-stage in the cumulative hierarchy of sets; that is, $V_\beta=\bigcup_{\alpha\in\beta}\mathcal{P}(V_\alpha)$ where $V_0=\varnothing$.

Comment: What is the definition of "rank"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$V_\alpha$ itself probably won’t have the desired property, but using the rank of $A$ to limit the possibilities is the right idea.

Let $\alpha=\operatorname{rank}(A)$; then $A\in V_{\alpha+1}$. Let $\mathscr{A}=\{B\in V_{\alpha+1}:B\approx A\}$; $\mathscr{A}$ is a set, and $A\in\mathscr{A}\ne\varnothing$. Let $\beta=\min\{\eta\in\alpha+2:\mathscr{A}\cap V_\eta\ne\varnothing\}$; then $\operatorname{kard}A=\mathscr{A}\cap V_\beta$. In particular, the definition of the von Neumann hierarchy ensures that $\beta=\xi+1$ for some ordinal $\xi$, so $\operatorname{rank}(B)=\xi$ for each $B\in\operatorname{kard}A$, and if $\operatorname{rank}(C)<\xi$, then $C\notin\operatorname{kard}A$.

Comment: Can you elaborate why $\eta$ (which I think you actually mean $\beta$) is a successor ordinal?

Comment: @Alberto: Yes, that was a typo. If $\eta$ is a limit ordinal, $V_\eta=\bigcup_{\xi\lt\eta}V_\xi$, so if $\mathscr{A}\cap V_\eta$ is non-empty, so is $\mathscr{A}\cap V_\xi$ for some $\xi\lt\eta$.

Comment: I can't see why $\{\eta\in\alpha +1\mid\mathscr{A}\cap V_n\neq\emptyset\}\neq\emptyset$: I can't find an element we're sure it is in. Would you please tell me? Otherwise, taking $\beta=\min{\{\eta\underline{\in}\alpha +1\mid\mathscr{A}\cap V_n\neq\emptyset\}}$ seems fine since $\{\eta\underline{\in}\alpha +1\mid\mathscr{A}\cap V_n\neq\emptyset\}\neq\emptyset$ because $\alpha+1\in\{\eta\underline{\in}\alpha +1\mid\mathscr{A}\cap V_n\neq\emptyset\}$ since $\mathscr{A}\neq\emptyset$ and $\mathscr{A}\subseteq V_{\alpha+1}$.

Comment: @Scientifica: That looks like a mental hiccup on my part. If I did have some reason back then, I’m not seeing it now. I’ll just change $\eta\in\alpha+1$ to $\eta\in\alpha+2$.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Scientifica: You’re very welcome.